# Entity Framework does not read column Precision from existing database

Tags: entity-framework

I have an existing database that includes a column defined as `MinimumInterestRate DECIMAL(10, 8)`.

I have an Entity Framework mapping that includes

```
Property(t => t.MinimumInterestRate).HasColumnName("MinimumInterestRate")
```

When I save records to the database, Entity Framework is treating my column as though it had a scale of 2, not 8 and silently recording a value in the database that is not the value I'm trying to write there.

I note that there's a `.HasPrecision(Precision, Scale)` method on the mapping entry that I could use to notify Entity Framework of the definition of my column.  However, it seems insane to me that I would have to keep this piece of information (easily derivable from the database) in two locations, and keep it synchronized.

This is not a code-first situation, the database and Entity Framework mapping were created separately and manually.

Is there any way to instruct Entity Framework to read the precision and scale from the database?  Failing that, is there any way to instruct Entity Framework to throw an error rather than save incorrect data for DECIMAL fields?

Comment: Afaik, you just have to have your mapping defined. It is because the physical model could potentially differ from what you have in your mapping. If insert/update works, ef will never suspect anything is wrong between database and the mapping.

Comment: Why should EF even *care* what the database precision is (except in the case where you're trying to create the DB from the model)?  It can just pass the value to the database and let the database be responsible for saving it or not.  Why is there a need for Entity Framework to make this decision to alter my value rather?

Comment: I believe this is because EF wants to be smart and apply casting (or avoid it) when you for example compare the column value to a decimal const. Depending on the actual const passed, a cast may be necessary or not. It might be interesting to log the actual insert query in your scenario, thoguh. Does the casting occur?